# Using hooks on react date picker

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm created a contact form that sends the data to an email and I want to be able to use the react date picker. I've successfully managed to get all other input fields to save in the state and send using NodeMailer however the date doesn't have a name assigned to it, like the other (example: fullName) so I'm not sure how to add it on so I can easily retract in the backend like I'm doing for the other fields (req.body.fullName). Appreciate any help :)
[image]

```
  const [startDate, setStartDate] = useState(new Date());

  <DatePicker
    selected={startDate}
    onChange={(date) => setStartDate(date)}
    inline
   />
```

Comment: Hey are you able to send the date to your backend ? can you add a clear pic of the JSON ?

Comment: You need to add an object to your state var for the `new Date`: It should look something like  
`const [startDate, setStartDate] = useState({varOne:new Date()})`

Answer (score 0):

You are probably checking the states using React Browser Extension. 
There you will see something like this:

```
State: xyz
State: abc
```

It doesn't display the name of the state only shows the value.
Say you initialized two states:

```
const [a, setA] = useState(1);
const [b, setB] = useState({'var1': 'val1', 'var2':'val2'});
```

Using React extension you can see:

```
State: 1
State: {'var1': 'val1', 'var2':'val2'}
```

But these both have the name associated with it `a` and `b` respectively.
You can access these by their names only.
So, here your state name is `startDate`.
Try:

```
console.log(startDate)
```

Your date will be printed. And send it in the body of the API call. And you can access it on the backend using `req.body.startDate`.